# why is api calls from the pysyft library causing a ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, torch, modulenotfounderror, federated-learning, pysyft

I am trying to work on a federated learning project and I am just at the beginning. I tried to import a class called "BaseDataset" from the pysyft library as shown in the following.

```
import syft.frameworks.torch.fl.dataset as st

dataset = st.BaseDataset(train_inputs[:train_idx], train_labels[:train_idx])
```

However the follwing error is poping up. I have checked the documentation from [here](https://pysyftbenardi.readthedocs.io/en/sphinx_backup/api/syft/frameworks/torch/fl/dataset/index.html?highlight=BaseDataset#syft.frameworks.torch.fl.dataset.BaseDataset)Any help will be much appreciated.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-f2dbf9acefcc> in <module>
----> 1 import syft.frameworks.torch.fl.dataset as st

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'syft.frameworks'
```

P.S. I am on pysyft version 0.7.0

```
Name: syft
Version: 0.7.0
Summary: Perform numpy-like analysis on data that remains in someone elses server
Home-page: https://openmined.github.io/PySyft/
Author: OpenMined
Author-email: info@openmined.org
License: Apache-2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages
Requires: ascii-magic, bcrypt, boto3, cachetools, flax, forbiddenfruit, gevent, jax, jaxlib, loguru, matplotlib, names, numpy, packaging, pandas, protobuf, pyarrow, pycapnp, pydantic, pyjwt, pympler, pynacl, redis, requests, requests-toolbelt, sqlalchemy, torch, tqdm, typing-extensions
Required-by:
```

I tried to import a class from the module. However a `ModuleNotFoundError` error is still persisting.